# List of lists model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

So this is what I have:

```
public class ModelA
{
  public List<List<ModelB>> PropertyA
  {
      get;
      set;
  }
}

public class ModelB
{
  public string PropertyB
  {
      get;
      set;
  }
}
```

and i want to data bind it to input so when I post it comes as an object to a controller.
I can not use JSON for this it must be bound.

the input name should be something like PropertyA[0].[0].PropertyB but i am missing something

Comment: @Ballbin there is a dot but is that correct way to do it EDIT: Shouldnt be ok i will try

Comment: Ok thank you very much that was an answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a '.' between `[0].[0]` in `PropertyA[0].[0].Property`B it should look like `PropertyA[0][0].PropertyB` since you are referencing by index.